# Django shows object reference in foreign key column

Tags: django

I have 2 classes defined in my models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    job_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    min_salary = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_salary = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobs'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_id

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField()
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job')
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    commission_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name ='employee')
    department_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employees'
        def __str__(self):
           return self.employee_id
        def __unicode__(self):
           return self.employee_id
```

The issue is with foreign keys, on Employees admin page the Job field correctly displays drop-down with all possible job_ids, but the manager field displays drop-down with all entries equal "Employee object". I suspect this is because manager is a foreign key to `self.employee`.

How do I fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the `__str__` and `__unicode__` methods on your `Employee.Meta` class.

De-indent them four space and you should be good:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=25)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField()
    job = models.ForeignKey('Job')
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    commission_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name ='employee')
    department_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employees'

    def __str__(self):
       return self.employee_id
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.employee_id
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, that fixed it. You would not believe how much time I've spent searching the web and trying to figure out what is it I'm doing wrong. Perhaps that indent alignment is not the most user friendly feature of python...

Answer (score 0):

Add `__unicode__()` or `__str__()` method in your `Employee` model as you have done in `Job`.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email #or whatever string you want
```

This method is used to represent objects as string in django.